# JW Platform - get my playlists(channels) list by keyword

Tags: jwplayer

I use BotrAPI v1.4 to get videos from my JWP account with next call:

```
$response = $botr_api->call("/videos/list",array('text'=>($keyword),'total_limit'=>$totalLimit));
```

But how can I receive my playlists(channels) from my account? There are no PHP examples of it.

Comment: Hi Alex, how could you achieve this? Means can we get playlists from the API? Please help

Comment: Hi Dushyant, see the Josie's answer below.

Comment: Thank you. So channels and playlists refers to same?

Comment: Exactly ))
https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/methods/channels/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `/channels/list {search: 'keyword'}` to retrieve channels based on keyword search. There's documentation available at: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/methods/channels/list.html